# Android: onBackPressed is not called when EditText is focused

Tags: java, android

There is an EditText on the activity, I click on that EditText, and the input method pops up. Then

1. I press on the back button, the `onBackPressed` method defined in the activity is not called, but the input method is hidden now.
2. I press on the back button again, the `onBackPressed` method is called this time.

My question is, why is `onBackPressed` method not called for the first time? And how can I make it work?

Here is my code.

#### MainActivity.java

```
package com.dict.androidtest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.d("AndroidTest", "onBackPressed");
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

#### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activityMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EditText has it's own listener and on back pressed method that responds when the editing window is active. onBackPressed() method works when the activity itself is directly listening for clicks.

Answer (score 4):

You can add an override that textfieldAction listener for it like below

```
textEditField = findViewById(android.R.id.editText )
textEditField.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() { 
    @Override 
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent event) { 
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) { 
           onBackPressed();
           return true;
        } 
        return false; 
    } 
});
```